# p5.js WEBGL / object centred when resizing the window

Tags: canvas, p5.js

I've a WEBGL canvas on top of a 2D one, in which I placed an object. I'd like the object to be always positioned in the center of the window. As it is right now, when I drag and resize the window, the object doesn't move, it instead stays stuck into its initial position.

These are the specs I'm using:

```js
extraCanvas = createGraphics(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
image(extraCanvas, 0, 0);
```

I've tried both

```js
extraCanvas.imageMode(CENTER);
```

*and*

```js
image(extraCanvas, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);
```

none of this worked.

Any idea on how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this way:

```
imageMode(CENTER)
image(extraCanvas, width / 2, height / 2);
```